# eclipse: Maven POM file opens in "android" XML view

Tags: android, eclipse, pom.xml, m2e

When I have Android and the M2E plugin both installed for eclipse, the POM files are not opened in the POM editor, but rather in the android XML editor.

Is there a way to re-associate POM files to the POM editor after the android plugin has been installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on pom.xml and choose **open with -> Maven POM Editor**

to associate permanently see [Configuring Maven 2 POM Editor to open pom.xml files in source mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084643/configuring-maven-2-pom-editor-to-open-pom-xml-files-in-source-mode)

- Juno/Kepler (4.x): Maven -> User Interface
- Helios/Indigo (3.x): Maven -> POM Editor